# read json object one by one &show in recycler view

Tags: android

I have a Jason object that does not have any Jason array, so that I can display my list in the application one by one in the recycler view. I tried many ways Can you guide me?

For example, I want to access the value of the current, but this value is inside an object and I cannot access it.

{
"data":{
"message":"Success",
"status":200,
"prices":{
"USD":{
"min":"497000",
"max":"497000",
"current":"497000"
},
"EUR":{
"min":"544500",
"max":"544500",
"current":"544500"

Comment: Does the structure of the json always stay the same? If yes you can just create classes for each country code and let your json mapping library of choice extract them

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method, you will definitely get the output you require:

```
    private void Action_Get_String_Api() {

    String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";
    final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest  = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            "https://smartandroidcourse.com/userrequest/api.txt",null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject  response) {

            modelClasses.clear();

            try {

                JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("data");
                JSONObject price = data.getJSONObject("prices");
                Iterator<String> keys = price.keys();

                while (keys.hasNext()) {
                    String key = keys.next();
                    Log.v("list key", key);
                    try {
                        if (price.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
                            JSONObject innerJObject = price.getJSONObject(key);

                            String str_keyword_min = innerJObject.getString("min");
                            String str_keyword_max = innerJObject.getString("max");
                            String str_keyword_current = innerJObject.getString("current");

                            modelClasses.add(new ModelClass(str_keyword_min, str_keyword_max,str_keyword_current));
                            myAdapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, modelClasses);
                            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        } else if (price.get(key) instanceof String) {

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }


                }




            } catch (JSONException e) {
                //
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```